# Use Regex to Exclude any values that do not have a letter

Tags: sql, regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

For example, column below:

```
Col_A
    1
  1,2
 the1
TH,E2
 THEN
 1_Th
   11
```

My desired output would be:

```
Col_A
 the1
TH,E2
 THEN
 1_Th
```

I tried this but no luck:

UPDATED EDIT:

```
with new as (
select distinct COL_A test from TABLE_1)

select test from new
where test regexp '[a-zA-Z]'
```

Data Type = VARCHAR(16777216)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on snowflake this works:

```
SELECT column1 
FROM VALUES ('Col_A'), ('1'), ( '1,2'), ( 'the1'), 
     ( 'TH,E2'), ( 'THEN'), ( '1_Th'), ( '11')
WHERE column1 RLIKE '.*[a-zA-Z].*';
```

gives:

```
COLUMN1
Col_A
the1
TH,E2
THEN
1_Th
```

And given [REGEXP](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/regexp.html) is an alias for [RLIKE](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/rlike.html) this also works

```
SELECT column1 
FROM VALUES ('Col_A'), ('1'), ( '1,2'), ( 'the1'), 
     ( 'TH,E2'), ( 'THEN'), ( '1_Th'), ( '11')
WHERE column1 REGEXP '.*[a-zA-Z].*';
```

given these behave like `LIKE` which is a non-greedy match, the wildcards are needed to match all the prior and after tokens.

```
WHERE column1 REGEXP '.*[:alpha:]*';
```

also works

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

```
where col regexp '.*[a-zA-Z].*'
```

The syntax you are using for `like` is specific to SQL Server and Sybase.

Comment: This didn't return any rows unfortunately when I tried this

Comment: I'm not sure if Snowflake understands character classes, so I switched it to something more explicit.

Comment: still no luck :(

Comment: this doesn't work because the RLIKE explicitly puts a ^$ around the pattern, thus you will need wild cards much like you would for a LIKE

Answer (score 0):

Tested and working:

```
select * from TABLE_1 where REGEXP_INSTR(COL_A, '[A-Z]', 1, 1, 0, 'i') > 0
```

REGEXP_INSTR will return the position of the first match, so it will stop looking after that. Using REGEXP_INSTR the pattern does not have to match the whole column just the first match. It should be faster. The options after the [A-Z] pattern are all defaults, but required to add the 'i' option for case insensitive matching.